# how to find and remove array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to retrieve data from an array list? then when the array data has been retrieved and displayed, the data will disappear from the array list.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Watermelon"];
```

for example, I want to take a watermelon object. Then when I've retrieved that object, then I want to display it. after the watermelon object is displayed, the watermelon will disappear from the array list

Comment: Starting point - [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to retrieve an object by index and then to delete it you can do it like so:

```
function retrieve(array, index) {
  return array.splice(index, 1)[0];
}
```

the splice function will take one (because of the second argument) element from the array and will return a new array with that item, then we access the first and only value of that array and return it.